# Screenshot in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to take a screenshot with the code below:

```
public void screenShot() throws IOException, InterruptedException { //Take screenshot and save to file          
    File scr=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); //Destination where to store screenshot        
    File dest= new File("filepath/Visionscreenshot_"+timestamp()+".png"); // Copy the file to system ScreenshotPath         
    FileUtils.copyFile(scr, dest);      
    Thread.sleep(1200);     
}   

public String timestamp() {        
    return new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH-mm-ss").format(new Date());  
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   Vision.Screenshot.screenShot1(Screenshot.java:37)

Comment: Error is : thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at Vision.Screenshot.screenShot(Screenshot.java:37)

Comment: this `File dest= new File("filepath/Visionscreenshot_"+timestamp()+".png"); ` doesn't seem to be correct. Does the path `filepath/Visionscreenschot` even exists?

Comment: File scrFile = (driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE));  

FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("d:\\Selenium\\screenshot2.png"));

d:\\Selenium\\screenshot2.png  : Use your path

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to change this :

```
File dest= new File("filepath/Visionscreenshot_"+timestamp()+".png");
```

to

```
File dest= new File("<Some existing folder path from directory>" + "/Visionscreenshot_"+timestamp()+".png");
```

***Note : Please take care of the file separator as well.***

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File dest= new File("filepath\\Visionscreenshot_"+timestamp()+".png");
```

And make sure your file path is correct.